# AttributeError: __aenter__ Pytest AioHTTP

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, aiohttp

I write this test, but I am given this error:

```
cont = 14322, name = 'reddis'

    async def logs(cont, name):
    
        conn = aiohttp.UnixConnector(path="/var/run/docker.sock")
    
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
>           async with session.get(f"http://xx/containers/{cont}/logs?follow=1&stdout=1") as resp:
E           AttributeError: __aenter__

tests/test_logs_func.py:10: AttributeError
```

What am I doing wrong?

Test code:

```
import pytest
import aiohttp
from typing import List

async def logs(cont, name):

    conn = aiohttp.UnixConnector(path="/var/run/docker.sock")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
        async with session.get(f"http://xx/containers/{cont}/logs?follow=1&stdout=1") as resp:
            async for line in resp.content:
                return (name, line)

class MockResponse:
    content: List[str] = [
                "one",
                "two", 
                "three"
                ]

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_logs_normal(monkeypatch):
    name = "reddis"
    cont = 14322

    monkeypatch.setattr(aiohttp.ClientSession, "get", lambda *args, **kwargs: MockResponse())
    res = await logs(cont=cont, name=name)
    assert res == (name, MockResponse.content[0])
```

In the original, the `logs` function does not return, but outputs data to the console and I need to write tests for this function.

Comment: Which version of aiohttp are you using?

Comment: I use -  latest 3.8.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> monkeypatch.setattr(aiohttp.ClientSession, "get", lambda *args, **kwargs: MockResponse())
> ```

This line tells me that you are mocking what `ClientSession.get` returns. The original `ClientSession.get` from aiohttp returns an async context manager (which you can use with `async with`), but you have replaced it with `MockResponse` which is not an async context manager.

Comment: What can i do to make the test work?

Comment: I presume you could make `MockResponse` an async context manager. I'm not aware of whether Pytest has any convenient ways to do this. You could just define its `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` methods or use `contextlib.AsyncContextManager`.